# Raise exception if sqlite query is empty

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a method that do a sql-query and return a value. If empty it raise an exception. The code works as expected but it seems like there's a more clean way to do it? Or is it?

```
def get_song(self, number):
    db_cursor.execute("select * from songs where Id = ?", number)
    song = db_cursor.fetchone()
    if song: 
        return song
    else:
        raise ValueError
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the True statement doesn't improve your code (you just want to be assured it is not False) you could preserve some lines doing so:

```
if song != True:
    raise ValueError
```

or

```
if song == Null:
    raise ValueError
```

Comment: But, the True statement is returning a variable. Or am I missing something?

Comment: The variable is already assigned one line before, the return doesn't change the original content in it.